# Insect repellent alternative for mosquitos and ticks?

Tags: bugs

DEET seems to be the main insect repellent that works for pretty much all of the bug world.  I just don't care for it, it feels weird, smells weird, and likes to melt stuff.

Most the alternatives seems targeted for just mosquitos, not ticks.  IR3535 seems to have [some data on ticks](http://www.ir3535.com/en_US/effectiveness_of_ir3535/against_ticks/against_ticks.html) (10 people, really?).

What is the best alternative that works for both mosquitos and ticks?  Is there any data out there to compare all the repellents?

Comment: @BenCrowell The suggested duplicate question (and answers) seem to be focused on mosquitoes. The OP seems to be asking about _all bugs_ especially _ticks_. Could we consider it _not_ being a duplicate if reworded to be clear about this?

Comment: Consider discussing on Meta... could be a rather long, complex discussion.